# Ove Drilling the police-flashlight finger into the counter

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of **drills** in this paragraph,

> The colleague looks very happy, as people do when they have not been
> working for a sufficient stretch of time as sales assistants. “Hi, how
> can I help you?” Ove **drills** his police-flashlight finger into the
> counter. “I want a computer!” The colleague no longer looks quite as
> happy. He gives the first sales assistant an insinuating glance as if
> to say he’ll pay him back for this.

From A MAN CALLED OVE by Fredrik Backman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the word ‘drills’ means that Ove hit with force his police flash light finger onto the counter.

Comment: In other words, he prodded the counter violently with his finger, as though 'drilling' into it.